# WordPress custom post type admin page layout

Tags: php, html, wordpress, user-interface, admin

So I am creating a plugin which uses custom post types and I want to create custom layout/UI

I am aware of meta boxes, but I believe this is not the way forward.

Currently I am using this:

```
add_action('edit_form_advanced', 'my_add_to_core');

function my_add_to_core() {
    global $post;
    if ($post->post_type == 'my_post_type') {

        $tabs = [
            'General',
            'Settings',
            'Extras'
        ];

        ?>
            <div class="my-container">
                <div class="tab-group">
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <?php $i = 0; foreach ($tabs as $tab) { ?>
                                <?php
                                    $i++;
                                    $title = $tab;
                                    $slug = sf_safestring($tab);
                                    $classes = '';
                                    if ($i == 1) $classes .= 'active';
                                ?>
                                <li class="<?= $classes; ?>"><a href="#<?= $slug; ?>"><?= $title; ?></a></li>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <div class="tabs">
                    <?php $i = 0; foreach ($tabs as $tab) { ?>
                        <?php
                            $i++;
                            $title = $tab;
                            $slug = sf_safestring($tab);
                            $classes = 'tab tab_'.$slug;
                            if ($i == 1) $classes .= ' active';
                        ?>
                        <div class="<?= $classes; ?>">
                            <h3><?= $title; ?></h3>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

This doing what I expect, adding my HTML to the core page layout.

Heres the outputted layout:

[image: Out putted html]

But I feel this is not the right way to do it. It feels a little hacky.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: You can copy HTML from the DOM explorer. Secondly, there is a [WordPress Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Custom Meta Boxes is the correct way to setup your layouts for Custom Post Types.

Meta boxes are fully supported, portable groups of content. They have an array of pre-designed styles you can use just by inspecting and copying different class names from the core meta boxes. End users can also reorganize the meta boxes if they are not layed out in a way they are comfortable working. Beyond that, from the screens dropdown people can enable and disable the visibility of each meta box. You can also program default locations for each meta box to "start at".

If you want to make things a little faster for development you can use a a framework thats very powerful, popular and commonly used in the WordPress community. Its called ACF or Advanced Custom Fields. It can help you build your custom meta boxes for a premium CPT workflow.

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

I personally don't use it, as upgrading major versions can require a large update on all projects using the code. That said, it will shave days of development time off your plate and does some pretty amazing things out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer but we are finding meta boxes very limited for what we are intending to achieve. Though ACF is an awesome plugin (i use daily on most projects) this is not what I need. As I mentioned in my question I am building a plugin and using ACF to handle the backend is not best practice as my plugin would then require ACF to be installed as well.

Comment: Actually ACF is portable, in that, they have documented how to include ACF as a portable stable module of your code. It won't get updated, like a normal plugin, but it will continue to work the same as it did the day you pulled it down.

I do agree with you, in that I don't like the idea of dependency code. That said, you really only have 2 options. Build your own custom meta box code, or use a library as a dependency. 

What exactly is limiting about the Meta Boxes. You haven't really indicated why meta boxes don't work for you?